# Distribute LaTeX Package with Document

Tags: packages, external-files, build-system, dependencies

### TLDR

Is there a way to distribute a LaTeX package with a document and to use it during compilation?

### Situation

At our university, we're writing a lot of lecture summaries with LaTeX. Sometimes those summaries need non-standard packages, or sometimes there are version incompatibilities between packages between different LaTeX distributions / operating systems.

As an example, https://github.com/HSR-Stud/CN1 uses the `siunitx` package, which changed the name of an option between Texlive 2009 and 2011. Therefore, the document compiles on either Texlive 2009 or 2011 depending on the option name used, but not on both.

There are also cases of packages that are distributed with MikTeX, but not with Texlive (an example would be [Picins](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/picins)).

### Goal

Is it possible to distribute LaTeX packages along with a document and use them during compilation?

As a sidenote, in all our documents Makefiles are used to build the PDF using `latexmk`, which is included both in Texlive and MikTeX, so custom compile/build options could be passed to the used tools and environment variables could be set. That could be of help.

Comment: perhaps using `\begin{filecontents}{nameofpackage.sty}<lines of package>\end{filecontents}` before the `documentclass`? This would create the package in the working directory... Is that the kind of thing?

Comment: In the specific case of `siunitx`, provided you set at least one version 1 option in the preamble the updated package will pick this up and use settings and options which are appropriate.

Comment: The search path for packages is: `current directory->$LOCALTEXMF->$TEXMF`. Create a loacal texmf with your packages and they will be used  instead of the ones in $TEXMF

Comment: @Herbert that sounds like the perfect solution, but it doesn't seem to work. I added a "texmf" folder to the project folder that looks like this: http://hastebin.com/xeciramafe.txt Any clue about why it isn't working? (It works if I place that folder in my homedir)

Comment: @Herbert oh, it worked by putting the *.sty files (there were two of them) directly in my project root. But as far as I know, a package can also contain other files besides *.sty, is that right? Is there a way to keep package files together in a directory, instead of adding all of them to the current directory? In any case, if you put this information in a proper answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: test it with `kpsewhich picins.sty` if it is listed. However, a better solution would be `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/picins` But then yiu have to run `texhash`. The personal `texmf` is searched recursively.

Comment: In some cases this can be done, but big packages such as `siunitx` depend on many others being at a certain version. Only packages that have no dependencies (`\RequirePackage`) are safe to be distributed along with a document; those with dependencies may or may not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Linux the search path for TeX is

```
doc directory -> $TEXMFLOCAL->$TEXMFHOME->$TEXMF
```

`$TEXMFLOCAL` is `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/`

`$TEXMFHOME` is `~/texmf`

For `$TEXMF` and `$TEXMFLOCAL` you need a `texhash` when adding files. `$TEXMFHOME` is searched recursively.

All directories must have a structure compatible to TDS (http://tug.org/tds)